# WinMerge like Solution for c#

Tags: windows, library, c#, .net

Is there **DLL** or **Class** or **Software** you can recommend that returns the difference between two string[], as WinMerge does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. I think the code in my repository https://github.com/thieupepijn/TextComparer is exactly what you are looking for.